# Spring scopes in embedded web app in Jetty server

Tags: spring, jetty, embedded-jetty

I configured Jetty to start web app from spring context, e.i. there are two contexts:

- external context which runs Jetty
- internal which is run by Spring DispatcherServlet

Here is the definition of external context:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

 <bean id="servletHolder" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="dispatcher"/>
    <constructor-arg name="servlet" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"/>
    <property name="initParameters">
        <map>
            <entry key="contextConfigLocation" value="classpath:dispatcher-context.xml"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="initOrder" value="0"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="servletHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
    <property name="servlets">
        <array>
            <ref bean="servletHolder"/>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="servletMappings">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping">
                <property name="servletName" value="dispatcher"/>
                <property name="pathSpec" value="/*"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="contextHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
    <property name="contextPath" value="/spring"/>
    <property name="servletHandler" ref="servletHandler"/>
 </bean>


 <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg name="port" value="9999"/>
    <property name="handler" ref="contextHandler"/>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

It refers to `dispatcher-context.xml` which is "internal".
So far it work fine unless I need to inject beans from external context into controller's beans from internal context.

Is there any way to define bean in outer scope and inject it into controller? 
It would be useful in unit-test or using this server as a part of bigger existing app.

The full code is available here: https://github.com/zjor/embedded-jetty/tree/master/spring-mvc-jetty

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found a workaround, I've used a combination of Jersey with Jetty and configured everything via Spring.

Code is available here: https://github.com/zjor/embedded-jetty/tree/master/jersey-jetty